# Thread with streams

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose a thread in my program reading a file from disk, and it encountered an Error(outOfMemory) and thread got killed without a chance to execute closing of streams given in finally. Will it keep that stream open even after that thread kills?

Comment: the `finally` clause can still be executed on OOM (but may fail again due to another OOM). if a resource is not closed, I guess it will stay open, until the process is killed.

Comment: Good luck with handling `OutOfMemoryError`.  Sometimes it only means that the calling thread tried to allocate one really huge object and failed, and other times, by the time your handler has been called, it means that the whole JVM is royally hosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` block will still be executed.  However, if the JVM is out of memory, there's a chance that there will be a problem closing the stream, resulting in another out of memory error thrown from within the `finally` block.  If that happens, the stream will likely not be closed until the JVM exits.

Comment: So in a webapplication, if one stream was not closed after its process, it will be there in JVM as open even after we restart that container? We need to restart JVM to erase that stream from JVM?

Comment: As I have already explained, streams can be closed when garbage collected. I have also explained that after first OOM raises, it doesn't mean you have no memory available at all. It just means the requested ***Heap*** allocation don't fit into memory _at this moment_. OOM means out of ***Heap*** memory. Another thread (or an upper caller) may have allocate many data. More, that's big chance that closing stream doesn't consume ***Heap*** memory but ***Stack*** one.

Comment: thanks Warren, But i think I should have ask it more clearly. if we have a code which use a stream and leave it open after use, will that stream keep  opened in JVM even after we completes that stack (finish its main). Suppose GC not executed till that time?.

Comment: @LoganMzz Streams may be closed when garbage collected if their finalizers are run; however, there is no guarantee in the Java language that the finalizer will ever be run.  I do agree that most JVM implementations run finalizers, but it isn't something a careful programmer will rely on.

Comment: @JomyGeorge I'm not sure I understand your question.  Normally, execution of a main() method corresponds to a single JVM process execution.  Such a process may have multiple threads, each of which has its own stack.  If a thread allocates a stream, and does not close it, and the garbage collector does not run, then yes, the stream stays open even after that thread exits, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @WarrenDew JVM implementations must run finalizers (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6)

Comment: @LoganMzz "The Java programming language does not specify how soon a finalizer will be invoked, except to say that it will happen before the storage for the object is reused."  So what happens if the storage for the object isn't reused?  At best you can only count on them running when the JVM exits.  And since finalizers block memory reclamation, they can make out of memory errors more likely.  The best practice is not to use finalizers.

Comment: @WarrenDew The JLS says "Before the storage for an object is reclaimed by the garbage collector, the Java Virtual Machine will invoke the finalizer of that object."

Comment: That's what I just said.  Note that there's a difference between "collected" and "reclaimed" - and also that the JLS always allows the JVM to behave "as if" it obeyed the JLS even if it doesn't, under the covers.  For example, when a generational garbage collector copies an object from eden space to the old generation and reclaims the eden space memory, it is "as if" the memory has not been reclaimed.

Answer (score 2):

In most case it should be closed. But it mostly depends on memory left when hiting close method and reference retention you have on the stream.

OOM are raised when trying to use more ***Heap*** memory than JVM is allowed to. But it doesn't mean you have no memory available at all. After OOM is raised, a lot of memory can be available due to many reasons : the process just try to allocate a BIG array that don't fit into memory, many intermediate allocated objects may have been discarded due to raised exception, GC may have run deeper collection than usual incremental ones, ***Stack*** memory can be used to process stream closing, etc.

Then, most streams are closed when garbage collected. Generally, you open and close a stream in the scope of method, then when exited there's no more reference over it. Thus the reference become eligible to garbage collection and may close automatically (however you have to wait for GC to collect it).

Most software good practice are based on "best effort". Don't try to think/do too much. Make the "best effort" to clean up and [let it crash](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LetItCrash).
What are you suppose to do about a non-closed stream while your entire JVM is going away ?

In your case ("stream handling"), "best effort" is done trough usage of [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

If you are worry about overhead of non-closed streams, you just have to use [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) ("best effort" application) and MUST focus on reference retention which the real cause of "memory leak" in Java (as most Stream are closed when garbage collected).

The real problem about "non-closed streams" is related to limitation OS apply about number of "file descriptor/handler" that a process can have at a given time.

Thread aren't supposed to be "killed" and if so, you may quickly run into troubles as [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) aren't freed (which will cause more damage through your VM).

Comment: I think my JVM will be running even after an OOM in a particular thread. Wanted to check if that unclosed stream will make an overhead to JVM when it executing other part of that program (some other threads), or some other programs

Comment: OOM aren't attached to a particulard thread but have impact over the all JVM because it's exhaustation of Heap memory while thread specific values are stored in Stack memory.

In case of Stack memory exhaustation, a StackOverflowError is raised. Note, that JVM is free to allocate objects on Stack (according to "Escape analysis") or local primitives on Heap. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/loganmzz/b0620745b4f0dcad980f)

Comment: Any shared reference causes overhead whatever it's a stream or not. And you must focus on reference retention if you want to avoid "memory leak" in Java.

The real limitation comes from OS which limits the number of "file descriptor/handler" a process can have at a given time.

To conclude, make "best effort" by using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and don't be too worry about stream closing.